# Calcular o total de uma coluna table com base no checkbox pegando apenas os selecionados

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <form class="form-inline" action="registrosVazios.php" method="GET">
      <table id="tabelaCupons" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" border="1px" bordercolor="#000000">
        <thead>

          <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;width: 10px">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chkAll" onClick="checkAll(this)" />
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              DATA
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              PDV
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              CUPOM
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              VALOR
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php 
          if (mysqli_num_rows($resultImportaPdv) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImportaPdv)) { ?>       
            <tr>
              <td  style='height:5px;text-align:center'>
                <input type='checkbox' id='<?php echo $row["ie_cupom"]; ?>' name='<?php echo $row["ie_cupom"]; ?>' value='<?php echo $row["ie_cupom"]; ?>' onClick="verCheck()" >
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                <?php echo date_format (new DateTime($row["ie_data"]), 'd/m/Y'); ?>
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                <?php echo $row["ie_pdv"]; ?>
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                <?php echo $row["ie_cupom"]; ?>
              </td>
              <td style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                <?php echo round($row["ie_valor"],2); ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
      }
    } else {
      echo "0 registros";
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ela ta seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que preciso, quando eu marcar com checkbox ele calcular o total da coluna valor

```
                   <td style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                    <?php echo round($row["ie_valor"],2); ?>
                  </td>
```

somente dos que estão checados.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer, lembrando que o nome do checkbox pode ser diferente, e preciso manter assim.

Resultado Final esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para facilitar o processo optei por acrescentar a class `check` na checkbox e uma classe `total` nas colunas de totais.

Para cada checkbox a lógica a aplicar é:

- Definir o evento `change`
- Nesse evento buscar todas as checkboxs selecionadas à custa do seletor `.check:checked`
- Para cada checkbox encontrada navegar até ao total utilizando `closest` e `querySelector`
- Interpretar o valor com `parseFloat` e acrescenta-lo ao total
- Mostrar o total caso existam checkboxs selecionadas ou `0` caso contrário

Implementação:

```js
const checks = document.querySelectorAll(".check");
const divtotal = document.getElementById("total");

for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; ++i){ //para cada checkbox
  checks[i].addEventListener("change", function(){//definir código para o evento change
    //buscar só os checks selecionados
    const checksSelecionados = document.querySelectorAll(".check:checked");
    let total = 0;
  
    checksSelecionados.forEach(c => { //para cada check selecionado
      let trValor = c.closest("tr").querySelector(".valor"); //achar o tr com o valor
      total += parseFloat(trValor.innerHTML); //transformar em numero e somar ao total 
    });
    
    divtotal.innerHTML = "Total :" + total.toFixed(2); //mostrar o total
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <form class="form-inline" action="registrosVazios.php" method="GET">
      <table id="tabelaCupons" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" border="1px" bordercolor="#000000">
        <thead>

          <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;width: 10px">
              <input type="checkbox" name="chkAll" />
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              DATA
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              PDV
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              CUPOM
            </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
              VALOR
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         
            <tr>
              <td  style='height:5px;text-align:center'>
                <input type='checkbox' class="check" >
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                data
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                pdv
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                cupom
              </td>
              <td style="height:5px;text-align:center;" class="valor">
                15.50
              </td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td  style='height:5px;text-align:center'>
                <input type='checkbox' class="check" >
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                data
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                pdv
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                cupom
              </td>
              <td style="height:5px;text-align:center;" class="valor">
                39.12
              </td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td  style='height:5px;text-align:center'>
                <input type='checkbox' class="check" >
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                data
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                pdv
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                cupom
              </td>
              <td style="height:5px;text-align:center;" class="valor">
                4.70
              </td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
              <td  style='height:5px;text-align:center'>
                <input type='checkbox' class="check" >
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                data
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                pdv
              </td>
              <td  style="height:5px;text-align:center;">
                cupom
              </td>
              <td style="height:5px;text-align:center;" class="valor">
                2.78
              </td>
            </tr>

        
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Documentação:

- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)